# Undefined data in the email of my contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contacts

I should solve a problem with a contact form and I don't know where to put my hands anymore.

I have a form in HTML, then a validation in JS and finally an email sending in PHP.

The form data are: Name, Clinic, Email, Phone, Address and Valutation.

In the email I receive the data are: 
**Name**: *name entered in the form* 
**Email**: *email entered in the form* 
**Clinic**: undefined 
**Phone**: undefined 
**Address**: undefined 
**Valutation**: undefined

This is the code (HTML + JS):

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";

  $(".contact-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(".name");
    var email = $(".email");
    var clinic = $(".clinic");
    var phone = $(".phone");
    var address = $(".address");
    var valutation = $(".valutation");
    var subject = $(".subject");
    var msg = $(".message");
    var flag = false;
    if (name.val() == "") {
      name.closest(".form-control").addClass("error");
      name.focus();
      flag = false;
      return false;
    } else {
      name.closest(".form-control").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
    }
    if (email.val() == "") {
      email.closest(".form-control").addClass("error");
      email.focus();
      flag = false;
      return false;
    } else {
      email.closest(".form-control").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
    }
    var dataString = "name=" + name.val() + "&email=" + email.val() + "&subject=" + subject.val() + "&msg=" + msg.val() + "&clinic=" + clinic.val() + "&phone=" + phone.val() + "&address=" + address.val() + "&valutation=" + valutation.val();
    $(".loading").fadeIn("slow").html("Loading...");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: dataString,
      url: "php/contactForm.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(d) {
        $(".form-control").removeClass("success");
        if (d == 'success') // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
          $('.loading').fadeIn('slow').html('<font color="#48af4b">Mail sent Successfully.</font>').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
        else
          $('.loading').fadeIn('slow').html('<font color="#ff5607">Mail not sent.</font>').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
  $("#reset").on('click', function() {
    $(".form-control").removeClass("success").removeClass("error");
  });

})
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-xl-8">
    <div class="form-holder">
      <form class="row contact-form" method="POST" action="php/contactForm.php" id="contactForm">

        <!-- Form Select -->
        <div class="col-md-12 input-subject">
          <p class="p-lg">This question is about: </p>
          <span>How satisfied are you with the service that Lab offers? </span>
          <select class="form-select subject" aria-label="Default select example" name="valutation">
            <option>Very unsatisfied</option>
            <option>Unsatisfied</option>
            <option>Satisfied</option>
            <option>Very satisfied</option>
            <option selected>I don't have an opinion</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <!-- Contact Form Input -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="p-lg">Your Name: </p>
          <span>Please enter your Dentist Name: </span>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control name" placeholder="Your Name*">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="p-lg">Clinic Name: </p>
          <span>Please enter your Clinic Name: </span>
          <input type="text" name="clinic" class="form-control name" placeholder="Clinic Name*">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="p-lg">Your Email Address: </p>
          <span>Please carefully check your email address for accuracy</span>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Email Address*">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="p-lg">Phone Number: </p>
          <span>Please enter your/clinic phone number: </span>
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control name" placeholder="Phone Number*">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="p-lg">Address: </p>
          <span>Please enter Clinic Address: </span>
          <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control name" placeholder="Address*">
        </div>

        <!-- Contact Form Button -->
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-15 form-btn text-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skyblue tra-grey-hover submit">Submit Request</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Contact Form Message -->
        <div class="col-lg-12 contact-form-msg">
          <span class="loading"></span>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$clinic = $_REQUEST["clinic"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$address = $_REQUEST["address"];
$valutation = $_REQUEST["valutation"];
$to = "myemail@email.com"; 

if (isset($email) && isset($name)) {
  $email_subject = "Request to access to the Price List"; 
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" ;
  $msg = "From: $name<br/> Email: $email <br/> Clinic: $clinic <br/> Phone: $phone <br/> Address: $address <br/> Valutation: $valutation";
  $mail =  mail($to, $email_subject, $msg, $headers);

  if ($mail) {
    echo 'success';
  } else {
    echo 'failed';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: **Never** *just use* i.e: `$(".name");`  `$(".email");` etc.  as your selectors. As you know already `$(".name");` will get **every** `class="name"` in your document. Same goes for all the other selectors. Instead, use the second argument that will infer about the specific **parent** (FORM) in your case: `$(".name", this);`

Comment: "_then a validation in JS and finally an email sending in PHP_" And server-side validation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your selectors. You only use **classes** `name` and `email` for all your inputs.

`<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control name" ...>`
should actually be:
`<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control phone" ...>`
and so on for all the other inputs. **Change your selectors to the appropriate classNames.**

Also, **never** *just use* i.e: `$(".name");`,  `$(".email");` etc.  as your selectors. As you know already `$(".name");` will get **every** `class="name"` in your document. Same goes for all the other selectors. Instead, use the second argument (*ParentElement*) that will limit the *search* only to the children elements of the provided **parent**:

```js
var name = $(".name", this);
```

or rather, use **attribute selectors** like:

```js
var clinic = $(`[name="clinic"]`, this);
```

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE about validation:**

**never** trust the *client*.
JS validation should be used minimally, just as a UX tool to help, inform the user about basic errors/typos. The *real* validation, as well as all the related error responses, should be handled on the backend side.
Currently your PHP seems quite open to XSS attacks.

You don't need a HTML `<form>` in order to send data to the server. All it takes to an attacker is to find your route/path (usually exposed via the form's `action` attribute), take a look at the names in the source and manually construct a HTTP request, and send dangerous arbitrary data to your server. Just so you keep in mind.

Comment: Well very good points, but generally he needs to use FormData and jQuery validator for the Front-end. Backend should be also reorganised and strict penetration checks must be done. A lot of work to be done actually for a person having no experience.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I solved it using the different $ (`[name =" clinic "]`, this); 
But anyway it is a simple form reachable from qr code only for affiliate customers, which is why it is so sparse. But I also admit that I wouldn't be able to do better than that. Do you have an article/guide to follow to improve security?